# How to compile dvisvgm with texlive 2009?

Tags: math-mode, tools, texlive, mac, svg

I am rolling out my own `mathview.el` (similar to `preview.el` but aim to be more efficient) package for editing LaTeX in emacs. Currently it uses `dvipng` but I would like to use `dvisvgm` as an alternative. Could someone share how they compile `dvisvgm` with TeX live 2009 installed to `/usr/local/texlive/2009`?

The reason I am considering using `dvisvgm` is that text in pngs doesn't look as thick as normal text in emacs buffer. See this image

[image: mathview].

I am using Snow Leopard 10.6.4. Thanks.

**Update:**

I don't mind if this question is deleted. Basically the header files of kpathsea must be available. But my tl2009 installation is incomplete so I stopped trying. Also `dvipng` has a --gamma option to change the darkness of the font, which can be adjusted to make images blend better with text in emacs.

Comment: I can’t help you with compiling on OS X. However, `dvisvgm` is included in TeX Live 2010, which - as far as I know - should be released “soon“. The [pretest](http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html) should be mostly identical to the final version.

Comment: Upgrade to tl2010 is too big a change at the moment. But will do that in a few months time. Thanks.

Comment: I grabbed dvisvgm from tl2010 which doesn't seem to depend on anything else except those come with Snow Leopard. Sadly the output is inferior to inkscape.

Comment: Can emacs display svg? News to me....

Comment: For a long time. It displays svg perfectly; in fact svg has been discussed to be the default image format for emacs.

Comment: Is there a problem generating a PDF rather than a DVI, and running a PDF to SVG converter?

Comment: That's one way to do it. The point of doing it through `dvipng` or `dvisvgm` is that they are very fast (at least that's what I heard).

Comment: @Leo: How is dvisgm inferior to inkscape? (Not disagreeing, just curious. I'm starting to look into both; haven't used either yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dvisvgm` cannot be successfully built using the `kpathsea` library that's installed with TeX Live 2009 on Mac OS X. There are two problems, the first is that the shared library is broken, it cannot be used. This turns out not to be a problem because none of the binaries in the distribution link to the dynamic library. (Someone should fix that; it's probably an artifact of `kpathsea` using a custom libtool, `klibtool`, for some reason.) So the dynamic library and its symlink can be safely removed.

The bigger problem is that the `kpathsea` does not contain `kpse_enc_format` so the `dvisvgm` file `FileFinder.cpp` does not compile. If you comment out the line containing that (essentially preventing `dvisvgm` from being able to find `.enc` files), then it builds, but fails `make check`.

I tried compiling `kpathsea` myself to see if that would help, but I'm not actually sure how to configure it properly. You have to replace its `config.guess` and `config.sub` with newer ones to get it to configure. I'm not really sure how to get it to point at my texmf tree though. I copied the `texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` from my tree over the generated one (and fixed up lines ending in `\`) but after building, the `kpsewhich` program couldn't find my files.

The best part is that http://mirror.ctan.org/dviware/tkdvi/kpathsea.tar.gz doesn't actually contain `kpse_enc_format` either; the entire preceding graf was a waste of time. Oh well.

Comment: The Tex Live 2010 pretest message describes dvisvgm as a new program: http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I didn't go to that length myself.